# Set minimum row in PrimeNG p-table

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I use PrimeNG (version 7.0.4) `p-table` and besides configuring row numbers via `[rows]` parameter in HTML, I want to set minimum rows for p-table.

For example, I set `[rows]=10` and there are only 5 records at the last page. I want to display 10 rows even if there is only one record in the `p-table`. I look at [How to set minimum value of rows primeNG datatable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44222786/how-to-set-minimum-value-of-rows-primeng-datatable), but I am wondering if there is a configuration for that.

Comment: @IS it not possible? Any help pls?

Comment: You can add empty objects to your data if you want to display empty lines.

Comment: @Antikhippe I think the only way for now to do that, is not it? Thanks...

Comment: I think so... did you succeed ?

Answer (score 0):

This approach works like a charm:

```
if (this.records.length < 10) {
    let temp = { "Id": '', "Name": '', "Surname": '', "Age": '' };
    for (let i = this.records.length; i < 10; i++) {
        this.records.push(temp);
    }
}
```

Thanks @Antikhippe :)